# Azure Data Factory - Passing Parameters to Custom Activity PowerShell

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement that, I need to pass parameters to the Custom Activity(PowerShell). I'm using PowerShell code that i have uploaded (file.ps1) to the blob. So as of now we are modifying the certain values manually in the PowerShell code based on the requirement. I'm planning to automate the this code but not able to find examples. It would be really great if someone provides details around this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to parameterise your powershell code (file.ps1)

Eg :
param ()

And in custom Activity command you can have the below code:
powershell .\ps1 -Parameter1 @{pipeline().variable.Test}

Comment: Thanks. I have already found this and able to do it.